# My input is supposed to be a checkbox but renders as a text input box

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to use CurrencyFormat to render the code within the value property but the input shows up as one with a type of text as opposed to checkbox. [what is being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxBMB.png)

```
<CurrencyFormat 
                renderText={(value) => (
                    <>
                        <p>
                            Subtotal ({basket?.length} items): <strong> {` ${value}`}</strong>
                        </p>
                        <small className="subtotal__gift">
                            <input type="checkbox"/> This order contains a gift
                        </small>
                    </>
                )}
                decimalScale={2}
                value={0}
                display={"text"}
                thousandSeparator={true}
                prefix={"$"}
   />
```

Comment: Are you using an external library? If yes, which one? I am asking because the `renderText` props seems to render just text, not checkboxes or radios

Comment: I'm using react-currency-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
displayType={"text"}
```

Not:

```
display={"text"}
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-rgb-o2w94?file=/src/App.js:761-790